# Override admin block file issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, override-block

I am trying to override block file of adminhtml of sales module.

Below is the code of my di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" />

</config>
```

I have used the Address.php file from this path

> Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form

and moved
into my module , but the block file is not overrided,

here is the code of my block file

```
  <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;

   use Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
   use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
   use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
   use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

   class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $customerFormFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Options $options,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $addressHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressService,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $sessionQuote,
        $orderCreate,
        $priceCurrency,
        $formFactory,
        $dataObjectProcessor,
        $directoryHelper,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $customerFormFactory,
        $options,
        $addressHelper,
        $addressService,
        $criteriaBuilder,
        $filterBuilder,
        $addressMapper,
        $data
     );
  }

  public function getAddressCollection()
   {
    //echo $this->getCustomerId();exit;
    if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($this->getCustomerId());
        $customerMasterId = $customerObj->getMasterId();
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('parent_id')
            ->setValue($customerMasterId)
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create();
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter]);
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $result = $this->addressService->getList($searchCriteria);
        return $result->getItems();
    }
    return [];
  }
}
```

Anywhere i am wrong? Its not overriding into my module. Please anybody help me. Thanks

Comment: Please add code of your block file.

Comment: Yes, @RohanHapani, updated my block file

Comment: extend this file \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address

Comment: yes, changed with that n checked, but no effect

Comment: What do you want to change in this file?

Comment: I have added some custom code to get master id, in this function getAddressCollection, to get address from master

Comment: I have checked it directly in vendor file, its working but override to custom module is not working

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

create di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" />
</config>
```

Then create your Address.php file :

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;

    class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address
    {
        public function getAddressCollection()
        {
            // Do your stuff here
        }

        //write here function in which you want to add your code 
    }
```

**Update :**

You can add construct like this way. Add this below code :

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $customerFormFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Options $options,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $addressHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressService,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $sessionQuote,
            $orderCreate,
            $priceCurrency,
            $formFactory,
            $dataObjectProcessor,
            $directoryHelper,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $customerFormFactory,
            $options,
            $addressHelper,
            $addressService,
            $criteriaBuilder,
            $filterBuilder,
            $addressMapper,
            $data
        );
}
```

Remove var and generated folder and check it.

Comment: I think we need to use constructor here, because we are using searchCriteriaBuilder in that function

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: yes used above code, seems the block file is not overrided

Comment: any system log or exception log?

Comment: yes checked no, errors in log file

Comment: Try to do echo "call"; exit; inside function. If function not calling then you need to use plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84375/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Did you override this file successfully?  Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address.php

Answer (score 0):

When overriding a class, you must use the same class after **extends** in your block file, which you have used in preference in the di.xml file.

Since you have;

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address" />
```

in di.xml, you should change:

```
class Address extends 
  \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\AbstractForm
```

to

```
class Address extends 
  \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address
```

Please change it and then check.